# cmake3 - how to process CMakeLists.txt include commands and view result

Tags: c++, cmake, include

How can a CMakeLists.txt file be viewed with include commands executed, and included code in place?

Example: Imagine a CMakeLists.txt that has multiple includes, like so:

```
include(version)
include(options)
include(programs)
include(settings)
include(stuff)
// etc..
```

Is it possible to generate and view the assembled result after all the includes in CMakeLists.txt are processed? Ty :^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `--trace` or `--trace-expand` flags.
Both of them make `cmake` print every line it executes into stderr.
For `--trace` it prints lines as they are read<sup>1</sup>, for `--trace-expand` all variables get expanded first.

I usually end up with call redirecting stderr to `cmake.log` file:

```
cmake . --trace-expand 2> cmake.log
```

If the output is too long<sup>2</sup> for your needs, you may try to reduce it with `--trace-source=<file>`. 
Extract from `--help`: `Trace only this CMake file/module. Multiple options allowed.`

<sup>1</sup> Quotation marks `""` are sometimes lost.

<sup>2</sup> It is really long... First pass over almost empty project yields 14k+ lines of log. Successive calls only 500+. There is a lot of stuff happening in CMake guts.